# Query for value in object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple documents like:

```json
{
  labels: {
    label1Key: "label1Value",
    label2Key: "label2Value",
    ...
  },
  ... 
}
```

The keys of the `labels` object are arbitrary. I would like to query for the existence of specific values in the `labels` object without knowing the key, e.g. I want all data that contain `label2Value` as a value in the `labels` object.

I've tried to solve this via an `exists` query, but this way I can only access the key of an object. Is there a way to query for values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a [Multimatch query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) you can use wildcards on the field names

**Ingest data**

```
POST test_bene/_doc
{
  "labels": {
    "label1Key": "label1Value",
    "label2Key": "label2Value"
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
POST test_bene/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "label1Value",
      "fields": ["labels.*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 24,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_bene",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "RtBd_ncB46EpgstaHy3Y",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "labels" : {
            "label1Key" : "label1Value",
            "label2Key" : "label2Value"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Using multi-match, would it also be possible to use operators like `gt` or `lt`? For example I want to have all labels where at least one value is greather than 10.

Comment: to do that you can do something like 

query: {
bool: {}
}

Comment: Wouldn't I then need the value? So something like:

query: {
  bool: {
    must: [{
      range: { ... }
    }],
  }
}

Comment: Sorry, the message was sent before I finished. I forgot you dont know the name of the fields so for range queries use query_string GET test_bene/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "labels.*"
      ],
      "query": "[1 TO 2]"
    }
  }
}

Comment: on your example would be [10 TO *] , docs here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Would it furthermore be possible to have a range query on a key? So how can I query for label1Key to be e.g. greater than 10?

Comment: I'm not following. If the key names are arbitrary how will you know the field name to do the query in the first place?

Comment: I don't know the field name in the first place. But the case could be, that a label is { 429: something }. What I want to query for is e.g. a label > 420 or something like that. This is now less related to the problem above.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? sounds like the problem is on how are you processing the data. But I can understand you cant change that. You should use a painless script for that case, if you get stucked open a new question. gl